# Typo3 eID script doesn't work

Tags: php, typo3-7.6.x

In ext_localconf:

```
   $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['eID_include']['send_mail'] = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('my_ext').'SendMail.php';
```

There is file SendMail.php in root directory of my extension. I am calling this script ?eID=send_mail  , but I have empty page. I tried debug this script but it isn't called. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had success using the following Code under TYPO3 CMS 7.x :

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['eID_include']['send_mail'] = 'EXT:my_ext/SendMail.php';
```

It is also important to clear the cache after coding this line. I usually de-install the Extension and install it directly again.

Good Luck, 
Uwe